# Is League of Legends on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

League of Legends is a MOBA (multi-player online battle arena) type computer game. It's set in the fictional world of Runeterra and sports several regions, ranging from Human Medieval(ish) to Magic Kingdoms and Steampunk cities.

Gameplay itself has not much to do with a storyline (as it's a MOBA), however, each champion (playable character) has a story behind it, and ocasionally there are events that expand the story of Runeterra.

Comment: Note, I ask this because I posted a question on Arqade which was closed for being off-topic. The question was regarding the origins of one of the weapons of LoL. Yet I'm not sure if it's on-topic/off-topic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I ask a question about video game based scifi/fantasy?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/319/can-i-ask-a-question-about-video-game-based-scifi-fantasy)

Comment: @randal'thor I actually read that question before posting this, but was still unclear, because most games have a storyline (Like Halo or Harry Potter adaptations), and League of Legends does not. However it has several stories around it

Answer (score 2):

### Yes.

> It's set in the fictional world of Runeterra and sports several regions, ranging from Human Medieval(ish) to Magic Kingdoms and Steampunk cities.

That sets it squarely in the realm of fantasy worlds, which are on-topic. However, note that questions about **the world itself** should be asked here while questions about **gameplay** should be asked on Arqade. From our policy on video game questions:

> I think you can ask questions about the **plot** and even production of the game. And you can certainly ask about the "expanded universe" you mention (books, comics & movies).
>
> Off topic would be **gameplay**, e.g. "how do I complete task X?" Please take that to [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).